# Make Emergency Alerts stay

Tags: settings, stock-android, alerts

Occasionally, I receive emergency alerts on my Android phone, through the stock/default mechanism.  It makes a loud, alarming/attention-grabbing sound and vibrates strongly.  The alert is displayed on the screen (which was locked) and there's a big OK button, which is the only button, and when I push it quickly to silence the alarm/vibration, the message disappears.  This may be before I've had a chance to actually read what it says in as much detail as would be appropriate.  Is there any way to get those messages to stick around and be dismissed manually, so that they can be read after the alarm is silenced?

Answer (score 1):

In Apps->Emergency Alerts, you can see a list of the previously received alerts and when they were received.